# vue programming this.$router.go(-1) don't go back

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

**In the Vue project, hash route 'this. $router. go (- 1)' is used, and click button the url '#' before has a '?' & Causes the previous page to fail , double click It will take effect but url err**

**this origin url**

```
url:http://localhost/payment/#/certifictionIndex/detail
```

**if i click goback the url change**

```
url:http://localhost/payment/?#/certifictionIndex/detail
```

** my code **

```
//button
  <button class="btn back p-cu-p" @click="goback">GoBack</button>

//function
  goback () {
      this.$router.go(-1)
    },
//route
{
    path: '/certifictionIndex',
    name: 'CertifictionIndex',
    component: () =>
            import('@/views/CustomerManagement/certificationIndex.vue'),
    redirect: '/certifictionIndex/certification',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/certifictionIndex/certification',
              name: 'Certifiction',
              component: () =>
                import('@/views/CustomerManagement/certification.vue'),
            },
            {
              path: '/certifictionIndex/detail',
              name: 'CertifictionDetail',
              component: () =>
               import('@/views/CustomerManagement/certificationDetail.vue'),
            },
          ],
        },
```

Comment: Why does '#' appear before "?"

Comment: Using push can jump route correctly ,but go(-1) can't goback

Comment: The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

1. submit

   This button is the submit button (except for Internet Explorer, which is the
   default for other browsers).
2. button

   This button is a clickable button (the default for Internet Explorer).
3. reset

   This button is the reset button (clear form data).

Comment: change button type can solve the question